# When I render my user input from a textarea in react, all of the formatting (line-breaks and tabs) are automatically removed, how do I change that?

Tags: reactjs, textarea, user-input, text-rendering

[How my text appears when rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfKhB.png)
[How my text appears in the textarea input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAjfr.png)

I am posting multi-paragraph blogs, some about poetry (where line breaks and spacings matter a lot). How do I make the line breaks and other spacing stay when I render the data? Can I make it so the user can put html tags in the textarea somehow? I am using firebase realtime database to store the data.

I tried changing the HTML tag in the rendered component from p to per, expecting to be able to use html tags, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

write this code on css file

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```